# How to recreate this jQuery content slider effect

Tags: jquery, clone

I am trying to recreate the effect the slider on this site has http://www.goldmansachs.com

The way that each box within a slide seems to have its own timing which then breaks away in either direction (left or right) is the effect I want to recreate with jQuery.

There maybe something out there that does this but I haven't been able to find it.
How would I go about creating this effect in a slider with each slide having a different number of boxes in them, it will need to auto detect the number of boxes and then create the animation depending on direction.

I don't need any of the URL or nav state change, I just see it being one slider with multiple slides containing the boxes.

Thanks

Comment: http://coursesweb.net/jquery/chain-jquery-effects

Comment: [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) used in conjunction with [delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Comment: Thanks guys. Is it easiest to incorporate this into an existing slider plugin or create a custom one?